# Spark: a partitioning puzzler

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have Spark job which is quite simple:

```
Dataset<Row> input = session.sql("select * from myTable")
        .orderBy(col("myColumn"))
        .withColumn("id", functions.monotonically_increasing_id())
        .cache();
JavaRDD<Row> grouped = input.groupBy("someColumn").agg(functions.collect_list("id")).toJavaRDD();
input.createOrReplaceTempView("input");
```

I run 2 versions of it:

- without manual repartitioning
- and with manual repartitioning via adding repartition(300) to dataset creation line (see below)

The version with repartitioning succeeds, while the version without fails with

> 21/05/25 19:29:48 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Exception while
> beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks (after 2 retries)
> java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to YYY

I cannot get the following:

1. what specifically prevents my job from succeeding without manual repartitioning and how can I find that information? I tried to run 'yarn logs' command, but failed to find anything in the output.
2. the order of repartition operator also matters:

The job succeeds if I repartition like

```
Dataset<Row> input = session.sql("select * from myTable")
        .repartition(300)
        .orderBy(col("myColumn"))
        .withColumn("id", functions.monotonically_increasing_id())
        .cache();
```

but fails if I repartition like

```
Dataset<Row> input = session.sql("select * from myTable")
        .orderBy(col("myColumn"))
        .withColumn("id", functions.monotonically_increasing_id())
        .repartition(300)
        .cache();
```

Why?

3. I know that there is a default partitioning operation in a plan, and as I have set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=300 it should be equal to repartition(300). But it is not helping. I checked execution plans to deep dive into this. This is a working execution plan, and what makes it work is Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(300). It comes right before Exchange rangepartitioning(myColumn#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, 300), and right before aggregation Exchange hashpartitioning(someColumn#5, 300) happens. Why these 2 repartitionings do not help?

Here is the plan that works:

```
ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[someColumn#5], functions=[collect_list(id#28L, 0, 0)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(someColumn#5, 300)    
+- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[someColumn#5],functions=[partial_collect_list(id#28L, 0, 0)])
      +- InMemoryTableScan [someColumn#5, id#28L]
            +- InMemoryRelation [..]
                  +- *(1) Project [...monotonically_increasing_id() AS id#28L]
                     +- *(1) Sort [myColumn#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
                        +- Exchange rangepartitioning(myColumn#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, 300)
                           +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(300)
                              +- Scan myTable
```